# Wireless home alarm system that does not need internet?

Tags: home-security

I am looking for an alarm system that does not require wiring between its different modules, but at the same time I do not want it to be on the internet.

The only two modules I'm looking for are door/window open and motion detector. And a siren of course. The max distance between every two modules is 10m and the max spread of the whole system is 20m. Drywall interior walls.

The system can use a Wi-Fi network that is not connected to the internet.

When triggered, the system should emit an audible siren. The idea is that the alarm would be in use only when people are inside, and if it triggers, the dwellers can call emergency services themselves.

Comment: It seems to me that this question is still quite broad. You could improve it by giving us specific requirements for the alarm system you're looking for. What do you need different modules for? How many of them should it support? What should the alarm *do* when triggered, if not connected to the internet? Is using a 2nd WiFi network with no internet connection acceptable if it's just used as the wireless connection between the security devices?

Comment: @Romen clearer requirements added

Comment: 0) Needs a third component; the siren.  1) What's the distance between door/window and siren, and 2) from motion sensor to siren? 3) Masonry, plaster-and-lathe, or drywall interior walls? A non-WiFi solution, AFAIK, will be less spendy, and guarantees it never gets on the web. 4) Would that be acceptable?

Comment: @K7AAY question updated

Answer (score 1):

[https://www.amazon.com/Linkind-Security-Starter-Control-Protection/dp/B07W49TS34](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B07W49TS34) is a non-WiFi system which fulfills all your requirements. It includes a 110dB Siren Alarm, PIR Motion Sensor, and a pair of Door/Window Sensor sets. It uses ISM (Industrial, Scientific, and Medical) radio frequencies and therefore does not need a license.